# Parallel.ForEach() yields no result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am trying to query a mongo-db parallely  using `Parallel.ForEach()` but I am not getting any results. But when I try to run the same thing in regular `foreach` loop I am able to perform the expected tasks.

```
var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
var secondaryObjectsDictionaryCollection = new Dictionary<string, List<JObject>>();

// This works
foreach(var info in infos)
{
    try
    {
        name = await commonValidator.ValidateAsync(name);
        await commonValidator.ValidateIdAsync(name, id);
        var list = await helper.ListRelatedObjectsAsync(name, id, info, false);

        secondaryObjectsDictionaryCollection.Add(info.PrimaryId, secondaryObjectsList.ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
    }
}

//This does not
Parallel.ForEach(infos, async info =>
{
    try
    {
        name = await commonValidator.ValidateAsync(name);
        await commonValidator.ValidateIdAsync(name, id);
        var list = await helper.ListRelatedObjectsAsync(name, id, info, false);

        secondaryObjectsDictionaryCollection.Add(info.PrimaryId, secondaryObjectsList.ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
    }
});
```

I want to perform this task in parallel only since different mongodb collections are involved and also to reduce the response time.

I am not able to figure out what's getting wrong in my parallel loop.
Any other approach to perform these tasks in parallel will also work.

Comment: Maybe removing all the `catch` statements would reveal an exception and helps you in solving?

Comment: @UweKeim doing that is giving me some expected exceptions from mongodb and after some time the application goes in break mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets take a look at more simple example that illustrates same problems

You have code similar to this

```
var results = new Dictionary<int, int>();

Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 5), async index =>
{
  var result = await DoAsyncJob(index);
  results.TryAdd(index, result);
});
```

Your code doesn't run because expression

```
async index => {...}
```

returns Task that is **not awaited**

like this

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 5), index => new Task());
```

*By the way, when you work with multithreading like in your example you should use **ConcurrentDictionary** instead of Dictionary, when you make parallel updates to avoid errors and deadlocks*

Best solution here not to use Parallel loop, but instead use **Task.WhenAll**

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(async index =>
{
  var result = await DoAsyncJob(index);
  results.TryAdd(index, result);
});

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 4):

Parallel.ForEach is not compatible with passing in a `async` method. If you want something similar to a Parallel.ForEach you can use [Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) and it's ActionBlock.

```
var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<Info>(async info => 
{
    try
    {
        name = await commonValidator.ValidateAsync(name);
        await commonValidator.ValidateIdAsync(name, id);
        var list = await helper.ListRelatedObjectsAsync(name, id, info, false);

        //Note this is not thread safe and you need to put a lock around it.
        lock (secondaryObjectsDictionaryCollection) 
        {
            secondaryObjectsDictionaryCollection.Add(info.PrimaryId, secondaryObjectsList.ToList());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
    }
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded });
foreach(var info in infos)
{
    workerBlock.Post(info);
}
workerBlock.Complete();
```

Comment: could you post explanation  why "Parallel.ForEach is not compatible with passing in a async method." , please

Comment: @Z.R.T. Sure, The function for the 2nd parameter is a `Action<T>`, however for async to work properly it needs to be a `Func<T, Task>` because it can't tell when the async job is done otherwise (basically you are passing foreach a "async void" function). Because of that as soon as the first await is hit it thinks the work is complete for that thread. Dataflow has a overload that takes in a `Func<T,Task>`

Comment: @Z.R.T. .NET 6 has now added a `Parallel.ForEachAsync()` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0