# Passing async method into Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, async-await, parallel.foreach

I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332341/parallel-foreach-yields-no-result) about `Parallel.ForEach` where it was stated that "Parallel.ForEach is not compatible with passing in a async method."

So, to check I write this code:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

    Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 100), async index =>
    {
        var res = await DoAsyncJob(index);
        results.TryAdd(index.ToString(), res);
    });         

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task<int> DoAsyncJob(int i)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    return await Task.FromResult(i * 10);
}
```

This code fills in the `results` dictionary concurrently.

By the way, I created a dictionary of type `ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>` because in case I have `ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>` when I explore its elements in debug mode I see that elements are sorted by the key and I thought that elenents was added consequently.

So, I want to know is my code is valid? If it "is not compatible with passing in a async method" why it works well?

Comment: *Don't*. `Parallel.ForEach` is made for CPU-intensive computations and doesn't recognize async methods. It doesn't *await* them, essentially converting them to `async void` fire-and-forget calls. Your method isn't async anyway, so it's not possible to say what the *correct* call would look like

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please post the source of your information. Thanks

Comment: `I want to know is my code is valid?`No. `why it works well?` It doesn't but you don't realize it because a) it doesn't perform any async work.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` - "Arrange for a number of threads to perform the following work in parallel" - `async` - "Well, there's no useful work for *this thread* to do until  something else completes this awaitable". Even if it did work (it doesn't, it's entirely synchronous as Panagitotis says), you're combining things in an odd way that overallocates resources and then ignores them.

Comment: @Seabizkit the OP's link already explains it. There's no [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2) overload that accepts a Task so even when the `async` keyword is added, the method is *not* awaited. This results in [an implicit async void delegate](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#implicit-async-void-delegates)

Comment: @DmitryS what *do* you want to do? If you want to call 100 URLs 10 at a time you could use a TransformBlock<T> with a DOP of 10. If you just want to fire some tasks based on a list of arguments you could use `list.Select(item=>Task.Run(...))` to fire all of them, then await them.

Comment: If you want to check the bad scenario with Parallel.ForEach, use a big `Task.Delay()`, eg for 10 seconds or more and do something that could throw after it, eg using a disposable object created before the `Parallel.ForEach`. Put that `Parallel.ForEach` in a console app's `void Main()` and watch how it *doesn't* wait 10 seconds before it returns. You'll end up with exceptions from the aborted waits or attempts to access the disposed resource

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the links!.. I'm going to re-read the one as its great with tips. butl not 100% convinced about "doesn't recognize async methods" say the method its calling a DB operation and it takes some OI time within the threaded Parallel operation wouldn't this benefit from async, as that thread can be returned to the thread pool?

Comment: @Seabizkit there's nothing to convince about. There's no overload that accepts a Task. Without that, there's no way to `await` any async calls. `async` doesn't await anything, nor does it make anything run asynchronously. `async void` calls can't be awaited, that's why they are considered bugs outside event handlers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code works only because `DoAsyncJob` isn't really an asynchronous method. `async` doesn't make a method work asynchronously. Awaiting a completed task like that returned by `Task.FromResult` is synchronous too. `async Task Main` doesn't contain any asynchronous code, which results in a compiler warning.

An example that demonstrates how `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't work with asynchronous methods should call a real asynchronous method:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

        Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 100), async index =>
        {
            var res = await DoAsyncJob(index);
            results.TryAdd(index.ToString(), res);
        });  
        Console.WriteLine($"Items in dictionary {results.Count}");
    }

    static async Task<int> DoAsyncJob(int i)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return i * 10;
    }
```

The result will be

```
Items in dictionary 0
```

[Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2) has no overload accepting a `Func<Task>`, it accepts only `Action` delegates. This means it can't await any asynchronous operations.

`async index` is accepted because it's implicitly an [`async void` delegate](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#implicit-async-void-delegates). As far as `Parallel.ForEach` is concerned, it's just an `Action<int>`.

The result is that `Parallel.ForEach` fires off 100 tasks and never waits for them to complete. That's why the dictionary is still empty when the application terminates.

Comment: You said in the comment that I can use list.Select(item=>Task.Run(...))
Why should i use Task.Run() in Select method? Can I use just like this: 
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(async index =>
            {
                var res = await DoAsyncJob(index);
                results.TryAdd(index.ToString(), res);
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Comment: Async is used to free a thread which would be waiting on "I/O" stuff, so in this case,  would it not be freeing some threads since the operation in the foreach maybe db access for example... Are you saying that this would be the case if the caller aka  Parallel.ForEach could return Task, and the fact that it doesn't... all the Task operations in Parallel are not able to implement the async lib correctly. Did i word that ok?

Comment: @DmitryS because you didn't explain what you really want to do. If you wanted to process some data items in the background *without* blocking,  you could use `.Select(..=>Task.Run..)`. The same would work if you wanted to test multiple algorithms and get the first result.

Comment: @Seabizkit `Parallel.ForEach` is specifically meant for data parallelism. That's why it doesn't provide any overloads for tasks, and actually uses the *current* thread for processing. It partitions the input data into as many partitions as there are cores and uses *one* task per partition to minimize cross-thread synchronization. It's a completely different problem from asynchronous or concurrent operations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos THANKS! i think that is getting a lot closer to the info I'm looking for.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you please have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499688/use-task-run-inside-of-select-linq-method

Comment: @DmitryS that's definitely *not* what I was talking about.

Answer (score 4):

An *async* method is one that starts and returns a `Task`.

Your code here

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 100), async index =>
{
    var res = await DoAsyncJob(index);
    results.TryAdd(index.ToString(), res);
});
```

runs async methods 100 times in parallel. That's to say it parallelises the task *creation*, not the whole task. By the time `ForEach` has returned, your tasks are running but they are not necessarily complete.

You code works because `DoAsyncJob()` not actually asynchronous - your Task is completed upon return. `Thread.Sleep()` is a synchronous method. `Task.Delay()` is its asynchronous equivalent.

Understand the difference between [CPU-bound and I/O-bound operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean). As others have already pointed out, parallelism (and `Parallel.ForEach`) is for CPU-bound operations and asynchronous programming is not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have asynchronous work, you don't need `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

    var results = await new Task.WhenAll(
        Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
        Select(i => DoAsyncJob(I)));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Regarding your async job, you either go async all the way:

```
static async Task<int> DoAsyncJob(int i)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    return await Task.FromResult(i * 10);
}
```

Better yet:

```
static async Task<int> DoAsyncJob(int i)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    return i * 10;
}
```

or not at all:

```
static Task<int> DoAsyncJob(int i)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    return Task.FromResult(i * 10);
}
```