# use Task.Run() inside of Select LINQ method

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Suppose I have the following code (just for learninig purposes):

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(async index =>
    {
        var res = await DoAsyncJob(index);
        results.TryAdd(index.ToString(), res);
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Console.WriteLine($"Items in dictionary {results.Count}");
}

static async Task<int> DoAsyncJob(int i)
{
    // simulate some I/O bound operation
    await Task.Delay(100);

    return i * 10;
}
```

I want to know what will be the difference if I make it as follows:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
    .Select(index => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var res = await DoAsyncJob(index);
        results.TryAdd(index.ToString(), res);
    }));
```

I get the same results in both cases. But does code executes similarly?

Comment: `Task.Run` schedules work on ThreadPool thread. This means you are pushing work to ThreadPool threads, but they return immediately because the only work they have is to start `DoAsyncJob`. `Task.Run` here is useless. Only if you replace IO bound work with CPU bound work, you will need to use `Task.Run`

Comment: You're creating `Tasks` wrapping `Tasks` (thankfully `Task.Run` knows you actually care about the inner task and unwraps it). `async` methods, *as an implementation detail* create a `Task` that represents their eventual completion and returns early. Why do you feel the need to wrap *calling* that method in a separate `Task`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task.Run` is there to execute CPU bound, synchronous, operations in a thread pool thread.  As it is the operation you're running is already asynchronous, so using `Task.Run` means you're scheduling work to run in a thread pool thread, and that work is merely *starting* an asynchronous operation, which then completes almost immediately, and goes off to do whatever asynchronous work it has to do without blocking that thread pool thread.  So by using `Task.Run` you're waiting to schedule work in the thread pool, but then not actually don't any meaningful work.  You're better off just starting the asynchronous operation in the current thread.

The only exception would be if `DoAsyncJob` were implemented improperly and for some reason wasn't actually asynchronous, contrary to its name and signature, and actually did a lot of synchronous work before returning. But if it is doing that, you should just fix that buggy method, rather than using `Task.Run` to call it.

On a side note, there's no reason to have a `ConcurrentDictionary` to collect the results here.  `Task.WhenAll` returns a collection of the results of all of the tasks you've executed.  Just use that.  Now you don't even need a method to wrap your asynchronous method and process the result in any special way, simplifying the code further:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(DoAsyncJob);

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Console.WriteLine($"Items in results {results.Count}");
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, both cases execute similarly.  Actually, they execute in exactly the same way.